# Theta method Local Error/Global Error- Numerical methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, localization

**Given the theta method,
$y_{n+1}=y_n+\theta hf_n+(1-\theta)hf_{n+1}$**

**Question:** a) How do you calculate local error? b) If the method is 0-stable, what is the order of the method?

I know how to calculate local truncation error (LTE)

To do LTE I would just Taylor expand around $y_n$ and I would result with,(not doing the whole derivation)

$(\theta-\frac{1}{2})h^2y''(t_n)+(\frac{1}{2}\theta-\frac{1}{3})h^3y'''+0(h^4)$

I'm just not sure if this helps me get the local error.

a) The only thing I have for this is essentially something I did for Euler method where you get the numerical solution and subtract the true solution.

$\bar{y_n}-y(t_n)$

Where $y(t_n)$ is the true solution. The only problem is I don't know if this correct, honestly I'm lost with the local error.

b) For the order if it's o-stable, I'm assuming it would a 1st order because the theta method is a 1st order numerical method? Still not too sure.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Compare with [Numerical estimates for the convergence order of trapezoidal-like Runge-Kutta methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213614/115115), same problem, more practical considerations. See also [Local vs global truncation error](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921554/115115)