# Convergence of Euler scheme for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods, eulers-method

Consider the initial value problem for the ODE
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dt}&=f(y), \\
y(0)&=y_0,
\end{align}
where $f$ is a Lipschitz continuous function on $\mathbb{R}.$ Since $f$ is globally Lipschitz, the IVP admits a unique solution globally on $\mathbb R.$

Now, consider the [Euler approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) given by
\begin{align}
y^{n+1}=y^
n+ \Delta t f(y^n).
\end{align}

For any $T>0$ and a $\Delta t > 0,$ with $N_0 \Delta t=T,$ how to prove the following estimate:
\begin{align}
\left|y(T)-y^{N_0}\right| \leq C \Delta t,
\end{align}
where $C>0$ and is independent of $\Delta t.$

P.S.: I am looking for a very general proof, i.e, for any time $T>0$ and with minimal restrictions on $f.$ I would greatly appreciate a clean proof or a precise reference that contains the proof.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921554/local-vs-global-truncation-error, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365839/eulers-method-global-error-how-to

Comment: Well-not exactly..They assume $f''$ is Lipschitz..I am looking for the estimates when $f$ is only Lipschitz

Comment: It's confusing. What are $y^{n+1}, y_n, y(T)$? function? value?

Comment: I think you are actually asking to show that the global-error for the Euler-method is of order $\Delta t$. You can prove this using Taylor-expansions (assuming differentiability, not sure how many times differentiable, of $f$).

Comment: @Rosy : No, only the local Lipschitz constant of $f$ in $y$-direction is used, in a region that contains the exact and numerical solution. Of the higher derivatives only their boundedness is used, that is, their continuity which implies bounds over compact sets.

Comment: To get global error order one, one needs that the local defect is $O(Δt^2)$, with a uniform bound. This is easiest but not most general if $y''$ is continuous, that means $f\in C^1$, at least piecewise. One could try to get along with $f$ being Lipschitz also in time direction.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your comments.. But I could not follow you completely..could you please give a detailed answer